# Using wildcards in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, wildcard, selenium-ide

I'm somewhat new to automation, and am learning everything auto-didactically, so forgive me if my terminology is a bit off. I've searched hi and low for an answer to this question, and I can't seem to find anything. I presume it's my small vocabulary when it comes to this stuff... anyway...

I'm attempting to write a test that performs all the actions necessary to complete a tutorial by using the recorder. However, for one particular step, the element ID changes. For example, the ID I'm trying to **click** is this:

```
//li[@id='message_661119']/div[2]/div[2]/a/img
```

However, for each new user that is performing the tutorial "quest", the number of the id changes.

Is there anyway to get Selenium to recognize, or use, wildcards? Example:

```
//li[@id='message_******']/div[2]/div[2]/a/img
```

Of course, the example above does not work.

Any advice would be immensely helpful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `starts-with()` for this:

```
//li[starts-with(@id, 'message_')]/div[2]/div[2]/a/img
```

It's one of the examples mentioned in [Locating Techniques](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.html) in Selenium's docs for `starts-with()`.

Comment: Man, I would kiss you if I could. Thank you **SO** much. I'll be sure to review the Locating Techniques more thoroughly. <3 <3 <3

Comment: your link is dead and I'm unsure if [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) points to the same content.

Comment: @rene: Doesn't seem to, as it doesn't mention `starts-with()`. It seems they've overhauled their documentation as the document is no longer available anywhere on their site.

Answer (score 1):

In Target field of the command in Selenium IDE where you can see message_123123 click on a dropdownlist and choose an option which is related to xpath:idRelative or if this one doesn't work then try another options which do not include that annoying message_123123 so this way you'll identify webpage element by it's location but not id. I solved my issue this way

Comment: well hidden. very useful for finding an alternate "target" selector.